# Where to set state after making an async call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to pull some data from dynamo db, store it in my local state and then do things with it. I can pull the data put I think I might need to handle async stuff, so Im using async await

```
async componentDidMount() {
//aws secret key stuff here
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-10-08' });
    const res = await ddb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    this.setState({ products: data })
}
```

I have a couple of questions. Im basically wanting to wait till the scan completes so I know that the data has been pulled successfully and then i can set state.

Firstly the linter is moaning that I should not set state in componentDidMount, so where should I set it?

Secondly, is the right way to await for some request to complete before utilising the data?

I did a `console.log(data)` where I have `this.setState({products: data})` and it logged the correct thing.

but when I try and iterate over my data like so:

```
{this.state.products.Items.map((product) => (
```

I get cant read map of undefined??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state in componentDidMount causes extra rendering. ([reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount))

> Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but
>   it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees
>   that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the
>   user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution
>   because it often causes performance issues. It can, however, be
>   necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure
>   a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or
>   position.

In some cases you must call some API and setState on componentDidMount.

I see 2 things you need to change. It seems **ddb.scan** gets a callback as a second param so you don't need the ascyn/await of Promises.

You need to use setState inside the callback in this case.

```
ddb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ products: data });
  }
});
```

If in other apps you use Promises you can use async/wait and use setState after the await.

```
const res = await promisecall();
this.setState(res.stuff);
```

Before accessing your products array you should check if it exists already.

```
this.state.products.Items
```

is undefined on first render pass. componentDidMount runs and sets it but

```
this.state.products.Items.map
```

has already thrown an error.

do something like

```
this.state.products && 
this.state.products.Items &&
this.state.products.Items.length > 0 &&
this.state.products.Items.map(etc...)
```

and it will only run if **this.state.products.Items** exists. You do this to prevent the first render (before setting state in componentDidMount) from failing.

Comment: when I set state in the callback though, it is falling over on the map() in the render method because it doesn't know what Items is

Comment: @TheWalrus I added a lot more explanation of what is happening

Comment: ok thanks. can you explain this...when I setState in the callback and then log the state immediately underneath, it is there. but when I log the state in the render method, products is an empty array and products.Items is undefined. so it's getting set but not persisting or not available in the render function...

Comment: @TheWalrus because that log happens on first render when you still haven't called any API or anything. Like I said in my answer setting state in componentDidMount causes one more render. So you have got to do some checks for the first render to pass.

Comment: ok I have put in the checks, but even on the 2nd render im not getting any products showing

Comment: @TheWalrus then probably there's something wrong with the data returned from the callback

Comment: i dont think there is because it's showing correctly in the logs and now on the second render the state is populated. and the page isn't blowing up anymore but for some reason it wont map over. strange one!

Comment: Is items an array? You can check the type to see if it is an actual array. Glad I could help

Comment: @TheWalrus try console logging inside the map function to see the items. If items length is greater than 0 it should go there

Comment: well I figured one thing out, I wasn't `.length`, so now that I am, I'm getting cant get length of undefined. because I think on the first render it is undefined so it blows up when trying to validate??

Comment: and yeh, i cant get inside the map function for this reason

Comment: ok nice one, that's basically working. it's only printing out one product but i believe that must be different issue than the current one. so i'll consider this solved. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Instead of making the `componentDidMount` async, you can call a function from componentDidMount that is async, that removes your linting issue

**Second**: You don't need an await with ddb.scan since it returns the response in callback. You could setState in it,

**Third**: Since componentDidMount is called after render, you initial state may be null/undefined and hence you get an error in the render method. Make sure you initialise the state as empty array or perform a validation

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.dynamoDBScan();
}

async dynamoDBScan() {
     //aws secret key stuff here
    const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-10-08' });
    const res = await ddb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        this.setState({ products: data })
      }
    });


}
```

and then in render

```
{
   this.state.products && 
   this.state.products.Items.length > 0 &&
   this.state.products.Items.map((product) => (
```

Comment: ok, but that just causes it not to blow up, how then can I get the products on page?

Comment: Isn't placing setState call in callback showing the result in render method, can you try `console.log(this.state.products)` in render

Comment: I have done, and it's returning me the empty array that is initial state, which is why im confused . coz I thought the callback would have to execute first and foremost?